# Facing fatal errors while running "yum update" command on CentOS 7/Cloudlinux 7

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kernel, yum

I am in desperate need of help with an issue that i'm facing while updating my system with the "yum update" command. My server is CentOS 7 converted to CloudLinux 7. I've been trying to find a solution for days, but no success as of now. Due to this error, I am unable to install "alt-php" versions too. I don't have the "yum update --nobest" option, I presume it isn't available on CentOS 7/Cloudlinux 7. I will highly appreciate any help!

Here's the complete error log:

```
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mysql8.0
Error: alt-python27-cllib conflicts with lve-stats-3.0.7-2.el7.noarch
Error: Package: alt-php73-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: alt-php82-8.2.17-1.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-54
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: alt-php51-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php51-mariadb1011
Error: Package: alt-php53-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php53-mariadb1011
Error: Package: alt-php73-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php73-mariadb1011
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mysql5.1
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mysql5.0
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mysql5.7
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mysql5.6
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mysql5.5
Error: Package: lve-utils-6.6.2-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-pylve >= 2.1-15
           Available: alt-pylve-1.5-16.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-pylve = 1.5-16.el7.cloudlinux
           Available: alt-pylve-2.0-4.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               alt-pylve = 2.0-4.el7.cloudlinux
           Available: alt-pylve-2.0-4.el7h.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               alt-pylve = 2.0-4.el7h.cloudlinux
           Available: alt-pylve-2.1-8.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               alt-pylve = 2.1-8.el7.cloudlinux
           Available: alt-pylve-2.1-8.el7h.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               alt-pylve = 2.1-8.el7h.cloudlinux
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mysql8.0
Error: Package: alt-php56-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mariadb1011
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mariadb10
Error: lve-utils conflicts with lve-stats-3.0.7-2.el7.noarch
Error: Package: alt-php72-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php72-mariadb1011-zts
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mysql5.1
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mysql5.0
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mysql5.7
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mysql5.6
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mysql5.5
Error: Package: alt-php82-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mariadb1011
Error: Package: alt-ruby25-rubygem-rack-3.0.8-2.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-ruby25-rubygem-rackup
Error: Package: alt-php-xray-0.6-21.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: lvemanager-xray
Error: cagefs conflicts with lve-stats-3.0.7-2.el7.noarch
Error: Package: alt-python27-cllib-3.4.0-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: liblve >= 2.1-15
           Available: liblve-1.5-16.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               liblve = 1.5-16.el7.cloudlinux
           Available: liblve-2.0-4.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               liblve = 2.0-4.el7.cloudlinux
           Available: liblve-2.0-4.el7h.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               liblve = 2.0-4.el7h.cloudlinux
           Available: liblve-2.1-8.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               liblve = 2.1-8.el7.cloudlinux
           Installing: liblve-2.1-8.el7h.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               liblve = 2.1-8.el7h.cloudlinux
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mysql5.7
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mysql5.6
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mysql5.5
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mysql5.1
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mysql5.0
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-percona5.7
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-percona5.6
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-percona5.5
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: lvemanager-7.11.0-1.el7.cloudlinux.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: lve-stats >= 4.2.0-1
           Installing: lve-stats-3.0.7-2.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               lve-stats = 3.0.7-2.el7
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mariadb10
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mariadb104
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mariadb106
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mariadb101
Error: lvemanager conflicts with lve-stats-3.0.7-2.el7.noarch
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mariadb103
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mariadb102
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mariadb10
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mariadb101
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mariadb103
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mariadb102
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mariadb105
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mariadb104
Error: Package: alt-php51-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-mariadb106
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-percona5.7
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-percona5.6
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-percona5.5
Error: Package: lve-utils-6.6.2-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: liblve >= 2.1-15
           Available: liblve-1.5-16.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               liblve = 1.5-16.el7.cloudlinux
           Available: liblve-2.0-4.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               liblve = 2.0-4.el7.cloudlinux
           Available: liblve-2.0-4.el7h.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               liblve = 2.0-4.el7h.cloudlinux
           Available: liblve-2.1-8.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               liblve = 2.1-8.el7.cloudlinux
           Installing: liblve-2.1-8.el7h.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               liblve = 2.1-8.el7h.cloudlinux
Error: Package: alt-php55-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: lve-utils-6.6.2-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: lve >= 2.1-15
           Available: lve-1.5-16.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               lve = 1.5-16.el7.cloudlinux
           Available: lve-2.0-4.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               lve = 2.0-4.el7.cloudlinux
           Available: lve-2.0-4.el7h.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               lve = 2.0-4.el7h.cloudlinux
           Available: lve-2.1-8.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               lve = 2.1-8.el7.cloudlinux
           Installing: lve-2.1-8.el7h.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               lve = 2.1-8.el7h.cloudlinux
Error: Package: alt-php53-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mariadb105
Error: Package: alt-php72-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: alt-php55-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php55-mariadb1011
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mariadb105
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: alt-php56-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php56-mariadb1011
Error: Package: alt-php71-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php71-mariadb1011
Error: Package: cagefs-7.6.9-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: liblve >= 2.1-15
           Available: liblve-1.5-16.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               liblve = 1.5-16.el7.cloudlinux
           Available: liblve-2.0-4.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               liblve = 2.0-4.el7.cloudlinux
           Available: liblve-2.0-4.el7h.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               liblve = 2.0-4.el7h.cloudlinux
           Available: liblve-2.1-8.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               liblve = 2.1-8.el7.cloudlinux
           Installing: liblve-2.1-8.el7h.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl7h)
               liblve = 2.1-8.el7h.cloudlinux
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-percona5.7
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-percona5.6
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php80-percona5.5
Error: Package: alt-php70-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: alt-php54-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mariadb1011
Error: Package: alt-php54-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php54-mariadb1011
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mariadb104
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mariadb106
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mariadb101
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mariadb103
Error: Package: alt-php81-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php81-mariadb102
Error: Package: alt-php52-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php52-mariadb1011
Error: Package: alt-php52-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: dracut-squash-049-191.git20210920.el7h.cloudlinux.1.x86_64 (cl7h)
           Requires: squashfs-tools
Error: Package: alt-php72-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php72-mariadb1011
Error: Package: alt-ruby26-rubygem-rack-3.0.8-2.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-ruby26-rubygem-rackup
Error: Package: alt-php70-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php70-mariadb1011
Error: Package: alt-php80-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
Error: Package: alt-php74-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php74-mysql8.0
Error: Package: alt-php71-mysql-meta-3-10.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-updates-testing)
           Requires: alt-php-config >= 1-52
           Available: alt-php-config-1-29.1.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-29.1.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-33.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-imunify360)
               alt-php-config = 1-33.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-38.el7.noarch (cl-ea4)
               alt-php-config = 1-38.el7
           Available: alt-php-config-1-39.el7.noarch (cloudlinux-base)
               alt-php-config = 1-39.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 23 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
alt-python27-cllib-3.2.49-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of liblve >= ('0', '2.1', '14')
cagefs-7.5.6-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of cagefs-lve = ('0', '1.27', None)
cagefs-7.5.6-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of liblve >= ('0', '2.1', '12')
cagefs-7.5.6-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of libsecureio.so.0
criu-lve-3.13-6.el7.x86_64 has missing requires of liblve.so.0()(64bit)
criu-lve-3.13-6.el7.x86_64 has missing requires of liblve.so.0(LVE_1_5)(64bit)
governor-mysql-1.2-92.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of lve-stats >= ('0', '0.9', '27')
liblve-devel-2.1-14.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of liblve = ('0', '2.1', '14.el7.cloudlinux')
liblve-devel-2.1-14.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of liblve.so.0()(64bit)
liblve-devel-2.1-14.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of libsecureio.so.0()(64bit)
lve-utils-6.4.13-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of lve >= ('0', '0.8', None)
lve-utils-6.4.13-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of liblve >= ('0', '2.1', '12')
lve-utils-6.4.13-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of alt-pylve
lve-wrappers-0.7.9-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of cagefs-lve >= ('0', '0.1', None)
lve-wrappers-0.7.9-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of liblve >= ('0', '2.1', '12')
lve-wrappers-0.7.9-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of liblve.so.0()(64bit)
lve-wrappers-0.7.9-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of liblve.so.0(LVE_1_5)(64bit)
lve-wrappers-0.7.9-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of libsecureio.so.0()(64bit)
lvemanager-7.9.1-1.el7.cloudlinux.noarch has missing requires of lve-stats >= ('0', '4.1.4', '1')
pam_lve-0.4-3.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of cagefs-lve >= ('0', '0.1', None)
pam_lve-0.4-3.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of liblve.so.0()(64bit)
pam_lve-0.4-3.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of liblve.so.0(LVE_1_5)(64bit)
pam_lve-0.4-3.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 has missing requires of libsecureio.so.0()(64bit)
```

I searched through all the sources that had fixes to similar issues, but none of them worked for me. The best solution that I could encounter was the use of "yum update --nobest" command; however, it doesn't work on my server with CentOS 7 installed.

I couldn't find any solution hat worked